WPF app does not start from a Windows Service
I have a WPF app and a Console App (.NET). After publishing the Console app, it will be installed and run as a windows service. This service will check periodically for new messages from an API. If there are new messages, it will start the WPF app to display the messages on the UI. The issue I'm encountering is that when the service is running, I can see the WPF app runs but only in the background. It does not initialize the UI. I followed the solution here but it still does not work for me. Here is the code for my Console app:
Program.cs:
using My_Service_App.Services;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using Topshelf;

namespace My_Service_App
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var exitCode = HostFactory.Run(x =>
            {
                x.Service<WindowsService>(s =>
                {
                    s.ConstructUsing(serv => new WindowsService());
                    s.WhenStarted(serv => serv.Start());
                    s.WhenStopped(serv => serv.Stop());
                });

                x.RunAsLocalSystem();
                x.SetServiceName("MyService");
                x.SetDisplayName("My Service");
                x.SetDescription("My Notification Receiver");

            });
        }
    }
}

WindowService.cs:
public class WindowsService
{
    private readonly System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;

    public WindowsService()
    {
        int interval = 1000 * 60 * 10; // (10 minutes)
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval) { AutoReset = true };
        _timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;

        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task task = PollMessages(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Start polling messages
        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Run(() => PollMessages(cancellationTokenSource.Token));
    }

    private async Task PollMessages(CancellationToken token)
    {
        // Fetch messages from API
        // Then, start WPF app if there are new messages 
            string wpfAppPath = ProgramHelpers.GetAppPath();
            if (!IsAppRunning("AppName"))
            {
                Process.Start(wpfAppPath, "NewMessage");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
    }

    public static bool IsAppRunning(string windowTitle)
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process process in processes)
        {
            if (process.MainWindowTitle == windowTitle)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }



There are security implications regarding starting a GUI process from a service. You should probably try to find another way to achieve your aims. However: https://jonathancrozier.com/blog/launching-a-gui-application-from-a-windows-service-using-c-sharp

I think you should separate the responsibilities of a Windows service from those of a desktop application that has a GUI. It doesn't make sense if the service has to display anything - then the application shouldn't be a Windows service in the first place. If this is a requirement that you have that service then you need a desktop companion application that is e.g., minimized into the system tray.

Then use this desktop application to either show notifications or to go into the maximized state to show those messages (if you believe that this kind of aggressive behavior is appropriate). You would simply have to notify the desktop application about the event (new message). The easiest solution might involve an AutoResetEvent. You can also use pipes if you need  more advanced communication between both processes.


This service will check periodically for new messages from an API. If there are new messages, it will start the WPF app to display the messages on the UI.

This will not work. It used to be possible (back in Windows 2000) and lead to security vulnerabilities so the capability was removed.
Remember your service will be running as a different identity (user): do not presume to give people "run as service" permission (bad for security: they could leave something running when they log off that could monitor the next user to login).
Instead you need to run the UI app all the time and make use of some IPC (eg. named pipes) to communicate with the service. The UI could sit in the notification area until something happens.
Using a named pipe allows the server to create the server end of the pipe with an ACL to limit clients to those with the NT AUTHOR|ITY\Interactive token and ensure they are on the same computer.
Once the UI client is connected the service can send alerts to activate the UI.
